# Update-join in MySQL extremely slow compared to the select query without indexes

Tags: mysql

I have a MySQL table with 100k rows that captures some server logs created as:

```
CREATE TABLE `logs` (  
  `id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `ip` VARCHAR(16) NULL,
  `date` DATETIME NULL,
  `session_time` SMALLINT UNSIGNED NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`));
```

I am trying to compute the session time as the time difference between consecutive rows of the same ip. I am able to achieve that with the following select query that takes less than a second:

```
SELECT * FROM logs AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id,
        from_unixtime(@diff) AS starttime,
        date AS endtime,
        IF(@diff = 0, 0, (unix_timestamp(date) - @diff)/60) AS session_time1,
        @diff := unix_timestamp(date)
    FROM logs,
        (SELECT @diff := 0) AS x
    ORDER  BY ip, logs.date
) AS b ON
    a.id = b.id
```

However, when I try to use the previous query in a update-join to update the time session, the following update query takes more than 600 seconds:

```
UPDATE logs AS a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT id,
        from_unixtime(@diff) AS starttime,
        date AS endtime,
        IF(@diff = 0, 0, (unix_timestamp(date) - @diff)/60) AS session_time1,
        @diff := unix_timestamp(date)
    FROM logs,
        (SELECT @diff := 0) AS x
    ORDER  BY ip, logs.date
) AS b ON
    a.id = b.id
SET session_time = session_time1;
```

What am I missing?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:** Here is the `EXPLAIN` of the `select`:

```
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+--------+
| id | select_type |   table    |  type  | possible_keys | key  |  rows  |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+--------+
|  1 | PRIMARY     | a          | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | 109029 |
|  1 | PRIMARY     | <derived2> | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | 108680 |
|  2 | DERIVED     | <derived3> | system | NULL          | NULL | 1      |
|  2 | DERIVED     | logs       | ALL    | NULL          | NULL | 109029 |
|  3 | DERIVED     | NULL       | NULL   | NULL          | NULL | NULL   |
+----+-------------+------------+--------+---------------+------+--------+
```

Comment: `WHERE ip = '...'`? Looks like you're updating all 100k entries but the ones you're selecting (`LEFT JOIN` = elements that don't comply to the select rules in the first group). Try using `INNER JOIN`?

Comment: Thanks Alejandro, but I don't quite understand your comment. Why would inner join be better? What do you mean  with the `where` clause?

Comment: Sorry, I should have explained it better. When you use `UPDATE`, you usually use a `WHERE` clause to filter which data should be updated. In your case, as you want to update for a specific IP address, doing `WHERE ip='<some_ip>'` should be better to process only data with that specific IP (I'm thinking that your query is processing every record in your table, even if not all of them are being updated).

Comment: About the `INNER` join, I was just wondering if it would be better than the `LEFT` one. When you have two groups that intersect (let's say `A`, `B` and `A&B` as their intersection), if you use `INNER JOIN` you will get elements from `A&B` (all the elements that match your `ON` condition and belong to both groups). `LEFT JOIN` will give you elements on `A` that **do not** match your `ON` condition, `RIGHT JOIN` will do the same with the `B` group. So, as you need records that match both groups in your SQL statement, then `INNER JOIN` should be better (assuming I understood your problem well).

Comment: I was just trying to give you options to try. I hope they help you!

Comment: How often do you have to do this task?

Comment: @AlejandroIván I do not want to update for a specific ip, but for all of them. About the inner join, I want the main table to have all the records, not just the intersection (although the table created from the select query has exactly the same records). Thank you anyway!

Comment: @RickJames I have to run it once a day in batch fashion.

Comment: @AlejandroIván actually an inner join solved the problem. I appologise, I discarded your suggestion without trying it!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start out with `session_time` being `NULL` in all rows.  Change the query in two ways:

- Add `WHERE session_time IS NULL` to the UPDATE (at the end)
- Set `session_time` to `NULL` if you don't have a closing time, else set it correctly.

The first night, it will be as slow as now, but after that, it will be much faster because it will be working on only a few of the "new" rows.

**Edit**

A `JOIN` needs (usually) an `ON` clause.  How about connecting `logs` and `a` with the `PRIMARY KEY` of `logs`.  The `EXPLAIN` show that it needs to run through 109K * 108K combinations of `logs` and `a`; it should be only 109K.

Also, remove `LEFT` unless there is some need for it.

Comment: Thanks Rick, I included your suggestion. However this query up there it already contain just the new information generated in one day (100k rows per day). I am still intrigued about what can be causing such time difference and fixing it.

Comment: If you are running 5.6, please post `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` and `EXPLAIN UPDATE ...`.  Perhaps that will show that the optimizer is doing something different between them.

Comment: I just added the `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` but I can't add the `EXPLAN UPDATE...` as I am running version 5.5.29 and previous 5.6.3 was not permitted.